# Why can't I edit verts on my model?

Tags: edit-mode, vertices

I just joined the hand to the rest of the body, but when I go to edit mode I can only edit the hand not the arm (like you see in the picture). Not sure why this is. This is probably an easy fix, but I can't figure it out.

[image]

Comment: your mesh is mirrored, are you sure you're working on the right side? maybe share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/